# How do I get the raw date value in my SPE report?

Tags: powershell-extensions

While trying to create a report compatible with the SPE Data Importer, I noticed that the date is formatted rather than the raw value.

How do I change this script to give me the date in the proper format?

```powershell
$templateId = "{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}"
Get-Item -Path master: -Query "/sitecore/content/Home//*[@@templateid='$($templateId)']"  | 
    Show-ListView -Property ID, Name, __Created, FullPath
```

[image: Sample Report]

Answer (score 5):

**Fun Fact:** SPE adds properties to items returned by `Get-Item` and `Get-ChildItem` (referred to as [automatic properties](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items#get-item-then-change-item-properties). With automatic properties your code can change from `$item.Fields["Title"].Value` to `$item.Title`.

Since we want the raw version of the field, we will need to populate the report using the raw field. In the standard Sitecore API you can access the raw field using the `Fields` collection.

**Example:** The following access the raw field value.

```
$item.Fields["Title"]
```

**Example:** The following demonstrates the changes to the script to access the raw values (denoted by `$_.Fields["FIELDNAME"]`).

```powershell
$templateId = "{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}"
Get-Item -Path master: -Query "/sitecore/content/Home//*[@@templateid='$($templateId)']"  | 
    Show-ListView -Property ID,Name, @{name="__Created";expression={$_.Fields["__Created"]}},FullPath
```

[image: Fixed]

**Note:** Incase you were curious, the *datetime* properties are formatted with the command `[Sitecore.DateUtil]::IsoDateToDateTime()`.